# Декоратор в java

Tags: java, python, аннотации, декоратор

В языке Python есть понятие декоратора, который оборачивает выполнение метода некоторым поведением. Есть ли в Java возможность реализовать такое?

Для примера, есть множество методов, каждый из которых открывает Hibernate сессию, что либо выполняет, и закрывает сессию. Для избежания повторения кода работы с сессиями, я бы хотел вынести это все в декоратор, в котором соответственно открывается сессия, вызывается основной метод, затем сессия закрывается.

Пока единственная мысль - реализовать собственную аннотацию, и ее указывать в нужных методах. Однако непонятно, можно ли на аннотацию навесить такое поведение, поскольку все примеры, которые я нашел, основаны на рефлексии и необходимости явного указания класса, с которым нужно провести обработку аннотацией, а таких классов и методов заранее неизвестно сколько.

Comment: Пробовали искать? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8_.D1.88.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D0.BD.D0.B0_Java

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит, поскольку вводит ограничение на пространство имен методов

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Полагаю, вы ищете AOP. 
Есть две распространенные библиотеки - Spring AOP и AspectJ
Что вам больше подходит - можете почитать и выбрать

[habrahabr.ru/post/114649](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114649)

[springbyexample.com.ua/2012/10/spring-aop-aspectj.html](http://springbyexample.com.ua/2012/10/spring-aop-aspectj.html)